# Laravel get query string

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following url 
`http://project.su/?invitee=95`

first i want to check the `invitee` in url, if the url have `invitee` then get the value.

What i have tried (controller) :

```
if(!empty($request->get('invitee'))){
   $user->invitee = $request->get('invitee');
}
```

The following code is not working .

I want storing the `invitee` result(id) in database.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use `$_GET['invitee']` because this is a query string not part of the Laravel routing.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To determine if an input value is present:

```
if ($request->has('invitee')) {
   $user->invitee = $request->input('invitee');
}
```

The **has** method returns true if the value is present and is not an empty string:

Comment: This only works for URL parameters not for query string.

Comment: I completely disagree @TheFallen

Comment: This method work for me on query string. Btw thanks @Depzor :)

Comment: This method also worked for me on query string LARAVEL 8

Comment: this method works perfect for query string, thanks @Depzor

Answer (score 21):

As far as Laravel 5.7 is concerned, the preferred way to retrieve query params is

```
if( $request->has('invitee') ) {
    $request->query('invitee');
}
```

or using the helper function if you don't have access to $request

```
request()->query('invitee');
```

Comment: current docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: Best answer as it's the most-current. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

In laravel 5.7, we can also use `request()->invitee`. By using this, we can get both, URL path parameters and query parameters. Say we have below URL

```
http://localhost:8000/users/{id}?invitee=95
```

To read `id` and `invitee`, we can use

```
$id  ✔
$invitee ✖ - Invalid
request()->id ✔
request()->invitee ✔
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get input by:

```
$invitee = Input::get('invitee');
```

For above 5.*

```
$invitee = $request->input('invitee');
```

Or

```
$invitee = Request::input('invitee');
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if `invitee` parameter exists:

```
if($request->has('invitee')) {
    // ...
}
```

To get the value of `invitee`:

```
$invitee = $request->input('invitee');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `$user->save()` anywhere? You should call `$user->save()` to actually persist the data.

You can always check by calling `dd($user);` right after the second line in you example if you are worried it is not set correctly, this way you can see what attributes are set in the `$user` object.

Also you can replace `!empty($request->get('invitee'))` with `$request->has('invitee')`.