# How can i pass parameter using ? in url in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to pass parameter using ? in url, like

http://example.com/somthing?name=myname&phone=12121212

when i add a '?' in Route file it shows 404

In my route file

```
Route::get('test?id={id}&name={name}','TestController@test')->name('frontend.test');
```

My controller

```
public function test($id, $name)
{
    
    dd($name);
}
```

But when i use it like this works fine

Route File:

```
Route::get('test/id={id}&name={name}','TestController@test')->name('frontend.test');
```

Controller:

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
    
    dd($request->route()->parameters());
}
```

i have a project with raw php i want to convert it to Laravel, so i don't want to change the url structure.

how can i achieve this in Laravel route.

Comment: it might be similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737019/laravel-5-2-get-query-string

Comment: Thanks, i got it. actually i didn't find how to get those parameter, now its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't define the parameters within the route.

```
Route::get('test','TestController@test')->name('frontend.test');
```

I prefer to validate and get the request parameters like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

...

public function test(Request $request)
{
    $params = $request->validate([
        'id' => 'required|numeric',
        'name' => 'required|alpha'
    ]);

    dd($params['id'], $params['name']);
}
```